# Play Integrity expect behavior for Futter App and how deactivate the API

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-play, safetynet

Recently, Google has deprecated the reCAPTCHA system. I have read the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/overview), but it does not mention how the system is validated from the users perspective. One of the most annoying things that could happen with the old reCAPTCHA API is showing images for the user to validate. This is particularly frustrating on mobile phones because it disrupts the flow of using the app.

I have two questions:

1. Can Play Integrity validate the user session with image-click section like reCAPTCHA does?
2. Can the IntegratyApi/SafetyNetApi be deactivated for Flutter applications on the Play Store? I have attempted to deactivate these APIs, but some users are receiving an error message stating that the application is not validated when they try to log in using Firebase Auth. This happens approximately 50% of the time.